# Python attrs library: define attr.ib(default=) using other attributes

Tags: python, attr

I am using the amazing `attrs` library to define a lot of object attributes in a very elegant way and it has been working like a charm so far.

The only problem that I am currently having is that I sometimes want to define default values by referencing other `attr.ib()` attributes. Here is some code that would run if the default for `name` were a static string:

```
import attr
from attr.validators import instance_of
import datetime

@attr.s
class Something:
    some_date = attr.ib(validator=instance_of(datetime.date))
    some_number = attr.ib(convert=float)
    name = attr.ib(validator=instance_of(str),
                   default="Generic Name {0} - {1}%".format(
                       some_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"),
                       some_number * 100)
                   )

something_instance = Something(some_date=datetime.date.today(), some_number=0.375)
```

The problem is that `name` doesn't see a `float` and a `date`, but a `_CountingAttr` object, hence I get an `AttributeError` (and a `TypeError` for `some_number * 100`). Since I can't reference `self` either, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this seems not possible with the default keyword at the moment. However, to achieve the same effect, it's possible to use the `__attrs_post_init__` method, which can used to execute arbitrary calculations after instance initialization: http://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html?highlight=attrs_post_init#other-goodies

In my example it would basically come down to adding

```
def __attrs_post_init__(self):
    if self.name is None:
        self.name = "Generic Name {0} - {1}%".format(
            self.some_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"),
            self.some_number * 100)
```

Credit goes to the attrs github issue tracker for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it without `__attrs_post_init__`.

Just use `default = attr.Factory(lambda self: ..., takes_self=True)`

```
import attr
from attr.validators import instance_of
import datetime

@attr.s
class Something:
    some_date = attr.ib(validator=instance_of(datetime.date))
    some_number = attr.ib(convert=float)
    name = attr.ib(validator=instance_of(str),
                   default=attr.Factory(lambda self: "Generic Name {0} - {1}%".format(
                       self.some_date.strftime("%d-%b-%Y"),
                       self.some_number * 100)
                   ), takes_self=True)

something_instance = Something(some_date=datetime.date.today(), some_number=0.375)
```